# Drop event of TreeView is not fired in Windows 8

Tags: c#, wpf

The `Drop` event in `TreeView` control of WPF is not fired when I login in Windows 8 machine. I have created all other events like `MouseDown, MouseMove, DragEnter, DragLeave, DragOver` which are necessary when you are using the `Drop` event of `TreeView` control in WPF. Because the same event is working fine when I am logging in `Windows 7 or XP` machines.

Is there any kind of compatibility issues of this control in `Windows 8` machine. Any suggestion will be helpful.

Comment: show, please, code

Comment: Can you do Drag&Drop with other applications on that Windows 8 machine? If not then It probably has nothing to do with your code but rather the system settings: [Drag Drop Not Working in Windows 8](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/nipuntomar/drag-drop-not-working-in-windows-8/)

Comment: @Bolu: For other applications like in the desktop of my windows 8 machine I am able to drag and drop.And the post u have shared i have done those things but didnt help.